# For Azure Functions is there anything line ASP.NET Core MVC Pipeline?

Tags: azure, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-functions

I'm working on a solution which is `Azure Functions` (`.NET Core 3.1`).
The solution has multiple HTTP triggered functions.

The goals are:

- To have common exceptions handling code
- To have common code to mutate response headers
- All of these must be done without need to copy-paste the same calls in all the functions

Curious if Azure Functions has anything similar to `ASP.NET Core MVC Pipeline` so that I could add some `middleware` which is executed before the function itself is called.

Questions:

- Is there anything line `ASP.NET Core MVC Pipeline` available for Azure Functions?
- Is there any possible alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Functions don't a request pipeline as such. Incoming requests are mapped to functions and are executed directly.

The alternate would be to leverage [Custom Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-custom-handlers) which allows you to run your own web server, which the functions runtime would start up and forward request to.